# How does one invalidate a UIPageViewController's cached page?

Tags: ios

I have a set of UIViews and their controllers representing different pages in a "document."  All are under the control of Apple's UIPageViewController.

The pages do not necessarily have static graphic content.  The content can change based on user actions when viewing any given page.  When that happens, my code invalidates the UIViews for all the appropriate pages using `setNeedsDisplay`.

But the view drawing update doesn't occur until a page is displayed >after< the UIPageViewController does all its magic animating a page turn.

The problem is that during that animation, UIPageViewController appears to use a cached version of the pixels of the old page.  The user sees the old content up until the page-turning animation is finished, at which time, there's one last update (because of the earlier `setNeedsDisplay` call) and then the final correct version of the page is displayed.  But the user sees this (flashing) change, which makes no visual sense, and violates the GUI illusion that what you see represents what you imagine.

I can't call each view's `drawRect:` method to force the pixels to change; `drawRect:` is reserved for the system to call.

So how does one get the UIPageViewController to update or toss a cached page to prevent this visually confusing situation?

Comment: Could you post some code for us to look? There are many reasons why you might be seeing previous versions of pages.

Comment: I don't really know which code to post.  Everything about the `UIPageController` otherwise works.  However, one pertinent factor is that the individual pages are being drawn using a `CATiledLayer` strategy, and the system caches the tiles and reuses them during zooming or scrolling.  Perhaps that's part of the situation worth considering.  I am just wondering if there's a general strategy for invalidating cached images in `UIView`s and their subclasses, when they are otherwise not currently visible on the screen.